# How do I get a Thumbnail of only one Image for putting it into an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, windows, image, thumbnails

I've got a Foto on the SD-Card of the device I'am using for testing.
The path:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test/test/test1.jpg"));
```

(Yes, the file allready exsits on the SD-Card)

I've managed to get Thumbnails of all Images on the SD-Card, but I only want this specific one.

How do I archive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is code for creating a thumbnail picture:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    }

    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
        //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }


options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```